# Deleting Grub and Replacing in

Tags: grub

Here is the situation. I have a Toshiba laptop running Windows 8.1 and Linux Mint 21.2 Mate. Been working for years.

Window 8.1 is coming to end of life and I need to upgrade to Windows 10, to support Photoshop - Lightroom (which are not supported under Win 8.1 now), etc. and my TAX program otherwise I use Linux 99% of the time.

I want to upgrade Window using the in place upgrade tool that Window provides. It work up to the point I do the initial boot to Windows 10 then fails. I believe it is because of the dual boot system provided by Grub. I believe I have to remove the Grub boot system and reestablish the windows boot loader which the upgrade tool I believe is looking for. I have found documentation on you site to remove Grub "Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader" and it makes sense.

What my question is: Once Windows is upgraded can I rebuilt the Grub boot system and thus avoid the Linux rebuild. I would like to do this so I preserve my /home partition which has all my software configurations like backintime schedules, etc. If so how do I do this. If I can't do this,

Second Option: Can I reinstall Linux with the in place partitions and get the dual boot back, I would only re-format /boot and / root partitions and leave /home alone.

I have /home backed up with backintime and I will do a cp of it to my external EXT4 device as well, I have Timeshift backed up all files in root and home also.

I also have a Macrium image of my Windows system also.

Can you help or point me in the right direction. Thanks

Also I know it is not a Linux problem if you know where I can get info to resolve my Windows upgrade issue without doing the above I would be great-full.
Thanks again and Seasons Greetings to all.

Comment: Are these UEFI installs on gpt partitioned drive? If so Windows should just change boot order in UEFI to make Windows first in UEFI boot menu. You still should have the Ubuntu entry.  But we have seen horror stories, so your backup are important.

Comment: UEFI installs on windows partitions - not sure about the linux but I will try to check. I think UEFI though

Comment: I changed the boot order with efibootmgr so that the DVD was first, then windows, then linux. Still aborted .

Comment: I have a Macrium recover boot on the windows boot manager.  So it is windows and then Macrium, could that be the problem.

Comment: Macrium is windows image coping software (from the UK).   I tried the update again after reordering boot order as above. Updated until the upgrade went to boot windows 10 for the first time. Then is backed out the changes back to Windows 8.1

Comment: Do not know Windows upgrade, probably better to ask in Windows forum. You should have Windows as default boot, as it typically wants to reboot multiple times on any upgrade. Once fully updated, then restore UEFI order to have Linux first in boot order.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please be sure to add all additional information also in the original post, as they might be overlooked if only found in the comment section.